# Select unseen random row from MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

We have a list of questions in a MySQL database and want it to show a random approved question to the user. When you click the Random button, we want another random question to be shown, but not any of the ones the user has already seen.

Right now the script looks like this:

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("aldrig") or die(mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM spg WHERE approved='1' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;") 
or die(mysql_error());    

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    echo "<div class='contentTitle'><h1>";
    echo $row['text']; 
    echo "</h1></div>";
}

?>
```

Comment: There's quite a bit of relevant information missing here based on what you have so far.  How do you track which ones the user has seen? Is there something not working about your query? What do you need help with?

Comment: You will have to store a list of questions that each user has already seen and update the list every time you show a new question.

Comment: I think the question is "How do I select a random row from a database table" -- the non-repeat can be handled with a "shown" flag column like "approved".

Comment: The problem is that I don't keep track of which ones the user have seen and haven't. That's my question. :) There's a fair amount of users and it has to keep track of it for each user - not just overall.

Comment: Oh. That changes the Vote to Close As Duplicate. Could you edit your question so it's clear and concise and shows exactly what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you fetch all the questions, and instead in your code work out which once have already been shown by taking them out of the result list and into a new list if you don't want to throw them away.

```
    <?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("aldrig") or die(mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM spg WHERE approved='1'") or die(mysql_error());
$answers = mysql_fetch_array($result);

start_session();

if (isset($_COOKIE["answers"]))
    $alreadyShownAnswers = json_decode($_COOKIE["answers"]);
else
    $alreadyShownAnswers = array();

$answerToShow = $answers[$randomIndex];
$alreadyShownAnswers[] = $answers[$randomIndex];
unset($answers[$randomIndex]);
$answers = array_values($answers);

echo "<div class='contentTitle'><h1>";
echo $answerToShow; 
echo "</h1></div>";

$_COOKIE["answers"] = json_encode(alreadyShownAnswers);

?>
```

something like this maybe?

**EDIT:**

The way to do it with cookie or session

```
start_session();
$_COOKIE["answer1"] = $answer1;
$_SESSION["answer2"] = $answer2;
```

now when you want to retrieve these values again after resreshing do this.

```
start_session();
$answer1 = $_COOKIE["answer1"];
$answer2 = $_SESSION["answer2"];
```

to use JavaScript for persistent storage use lawnchair: http://brian.io/lawnchair/

example:

```
var store = new lawnchair({name:'testing'}, function(store) {

    // create an object
    var me = {key:'brian'};

    // save it
    store.save(me);

    // access it later... yes even after a page refresh!
    store.get('brian', function(me) {
        console.log(me);
    });
});
```

**EDIT2:**

Updated the first code block with the new code, i have not tested this but something like that should work.

Comment: Yeah, that seems good so far.
I'll test it and see if it works out, but can it save the answers when I reload the page?

Comment: no if you reload the page it does not save the answer. You can use a js plugin/library to store persistent values or just store persistent values in the cookie manually.

Comment: Oh okay. Cookies isn't my strongest side. :)
Btw, if it makes it easier for you, you can see the site itself here: http://jegharaldrig.eu (it's in danish)

Comment: But I have like 120 questions. Isn't there an easier way than having 119 cookies?

Comment: Would you mind making a pretty much ready to use script? That would be really great!

Comment: The database contains id, text (the question) and approved (that can be 1 [approved] or 0 [not approved])

Comment: Oh, that looks like the right thing. Would you mind trying to put it in the script, so it's ready to use?

Comment: php please. that would be great.

Comment: are you familiar with the debug abilities in chrome F12, check if your cookie contains any values, and use var_dump($var) to check whats inside a variable at that time where you do the var dump.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. There appears to be no cookies. (The address for the page is http://aldrigspillet.dk/ny_index.php [this is the page where i'm testing this]